# check if multiple words precede current word

Tags: regex, r, string

I have strings of the following flavor:

```
Random Inc
A Non-Random Inc
```

I would like to remove the word `Inc` from all those strings wehre there are more than 1 word preceding it. The result on the above two examples would be:

```
Random Inc
A Non-Random
```

What is the right regex to plug into `gsub` for this? In particular, how does one specify complete words in regex? I thought it would be `\w` but this is a word character which does not seem correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` matches a word character, but in this case it seems you need to account for the hyphen and use a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html).

```
x <- c('Random Inc', 'A Non-Random Inc', 'Another Inc', 'A Random other Inc')
sub('[\\w-]+ [\\w-]+\\K *Inc', '', x, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "Random Inc"     "A Non-Random"   "Another Inc"    "A Random other"
```

First we match any character of word characters, hyphen "one or more" times followed by whitespace followed by word characters, hyphen "one or more" times. The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match *and any previously consumed characters are no longer included*. Then we match whitespace "zero or more" times followed by the word Inc. Since we use `\K`, we use an empty replacement because `\K` acts as a zero-width assertion.

Comment: this is great as usual - could i ask you to write up in words what is going on? i have looked on that explain web-site but it is still over my head

Comment: also what does "capture" vs. "not capture" mean with respect to groupings

Comment: Capturing means we group `( )` and capture what is matched inside the parenthesis. A capturing group can be used later on as a backreference or in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
([-\w]+\s+[-\w]+)\s+Inc
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/bD6uZ9/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean one or more non-space characters as complete word. If yes, then you could use `\S+`.

```
> x <- c('Random Inc', 'A Non-Random Inc', 'Another Inc', 'A Random other Inc')
> sub("^\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?$(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+Inc\\b", "", x, perl=T)
[1] "Random Inc"     "A Non-Random"   "Another Inc"    "A Random other"
```

- `^\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)?$` Matches the line which has exactly one or two words.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Causes the match to Fail.
- `|` OR (ie, consider only the remaining part of the string)
- `\\s+Inc\\b` Matche `Inc` and also the preceding one or more space characters.